# PHP Firestore without gRPC extention

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, web-hosting

I am currently working on a PHP project using Firebase Firestore, and I plan to deploy the web application using Heroku. However, it turns out that Heroku does not support the gRPC extension. I have been trying to figure out how to use Firestore without grpc, but the documentation is very limited and incomplete. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to upload a PHP web application with Firestore or how to use Firestore without grpc?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use gRPC and there's no SDK for your platform, the only option is to communicate with Firestore through its [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest).